# Calculating the area covered by the irregular shapes in an image (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to estimate the area coverage (percentage) of the irregularly shaped objects. The length reference is the scale bar: 10 microns.

I tied to use the canny edge detector/ findContours. But, it is not detecting any edges, maybe due to grainy background.

Also, how can I calculate the area?

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("Test3.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 10, 100)

cv2.imshow("Original image", image)
cv2.imshow("Edged image", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: make a mask, calculate the sum. -- Canny is not just useless here, it's counterproductive. that goes for MOST things people think they can use Canny for. -- deal with noise, threshold, done (almost). -- welcome, check out: [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: this is possible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oddG.png (3.73% cover) do you want an answer?